# Sending email with attached file in Django

Tags: python, django, file, email

I am trying to send and email in Django forms with attached file, but i cant figure out how to send the file(uploaded by user) without saving it locally. 
I have my form:

```
class PrintForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    supervisor = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[(str(sup.email), str(sup.name)) for sup in Supervisors.objects.all()]
    )
    file = forms.FileField()
    content = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
```

and my view:

```
def print(request):
   #  context = dict()
   #  context['printers'] = Printer.objects.all()
   #   return render(request, 'threeD/print.html', context)

   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PrintForm(data=request.POST, request = request)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name', '')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email', '')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content', '')
            supervisor = form.cleaned_data['supervisor']
            template = get_template('threeD/email/contact_template_for_printing.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name': contact_name,
                'supervisor': supervisor,
                'contact_email': contact_email,
                'form_content': form_content,
            })
            content = template.render(context)
            subject = "New message"

            try:
                email = EmailMessage(
                    subject,
                    content,
                    contact_email,
                    [supervisor],
                    headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
                )
                #email.attach(...)
                email.send()
            except:
                return "Attachment error"

            messages.success(request, "Thank you for your message.")
            return redirect('/index/print/')

   else:
            form = PrintForm(request=request)
   context_dict = {}
   context_dict['printers'] = Printer.objects.all()
   context_dict['form'] = form
   return render(request, 'threeD/print.html', context_dict)
```

So in my view, when i am sending an email, is there a way to call `email.attach(file)` which would attach file to a mail and send it but without locally saving the file? (form and view works fine, without file feature implementation)

EDIT:

 here is HTML code snippet, where i call for the form:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
        <form role="form" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% load bootstrap %}
               {{ form|bootstrap }}

            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>    Send a message</button>
            </div>
        </form>
 </div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Something like this:

```
def send_email(request):
    ...
    email = EmailMessage(
        subject,
        content,
        contact_email,
        [to],
        headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
    )
    if request.FILES:
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['file'] # file is the name value which you have provided in form for file field
        email.attach(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file.read(), uploaded_file.content_type)
    email.send()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Is there anything wrong in my forms when i say "file = forms.FileField()" ? Because using your approach for views, it still doesnt work, and it writes "This field is required." near the field after submitting, like there would be no file attached, even if it is

Comment: Edit your question to add html code of the form and also request.FILES value when the control comes to the view.

Comment: I have added my html code, which is quite primitive. I am sorry to say, but i'm afraid i dont know how to get  request.FILES value when the control comes to the view.  :/

Comment: There are 2 ways, use python breakpoint: import pdb; pdb.set_trace() at the start of the view (server control will stop there) or add 'print request.FILES' this will print the value in server log.

Comment: Hmmm. that's weird. I have first tried python breakpoint and after from submission i got a Pdb in console. I typed in request.FILE and it says: "*** AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'FILE'". and i have tried print(request.FILE), and i get error "'MultiValueDict' object has no attribute 'method'" and Exception Value: 
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'FILE'

Comment: Its request.FILES not request.FILE   !

Comment: oh, i'm sorry. I have just tried both FILE and FILES for print method and both gave the same error.
But using pdb i get: "-> if form.is_valid():
(Pdb) request.FILES
<MultiValueDict: {}>" and empty dictionary :O

Comment: add this attribute for the form tag: <form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form> This will definitely work

Comment: dang it.. still doesn't. But it is showing the file name now in request.FILES (in both methods), but after submission it still argues "This field is required." on my web :/

Comment: if the file field is not mandatory then you can make required=false in forms.py like this: file = forms.FileField(required=false)

Comment: it is mandatory, but i have tried that out to see if that would help, and now it's raising an AttribureError:  'str' object has no attribute 'get'. [that's how it looks](http://dpaste.com/3S2MTYK)

Comment: Abijith, are you sure that the syntax of email.attach('uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file.read(), uploaded_file.content_type') is right? Because it seems that that's the place where i'm getting the error now :/ I have tried removing ' ' brackets and now it passes attach line but on the line email.send() it gives an ValueError "need more than 1 value to unpack"